# SelectPdf Html to Pdf make Image and page in equal size

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, pdf-generation, selectpdf

I generate a card with html and then I convert it to pdf with SelectPdf converter. The problem is, I can't seem to fit the card and pdf page perfectly, without no "white paper".
My goal is that the card and pdf page are the same size, so i can print it.

[image: Card on pdf page example]

the code (c#):

```
HtmlToPdf converter = new HtmlToPdf();
var doc = new PdfDocument();
converter.Options.PdfPageSize = PdfPageSize.Custom;
converter.Options.PdfPageCustomSize = new SizeF(Convert.ToInt32(paperWidth), Convert.ToInt32(paperHeight));
doc = converter.ConvertHtmlString(cardString);
return doc.Save();
```

Comment: Can you share the html code/ view code?

Answer (score 0):

If you use  `div` element, in CSS you can use `@media` print to specify formatting when printed.

```
<html>
<style>
@media print {
        body{
            width: 21cm;
            height: 29.7cm;
       } 
    }
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .pageA4 {
        width: 210mm;
        height: 297mm;
    }
</style>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="pageA4" style="background-color:yellow"><h1>page 1</h1></div>
   
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to know more , read [this](https://selectpdf.com/html-to-pdf/docs/html/ResizingContentDuringConversion.htm)